# Chrome Developer - Elements section broken

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I was wondering if anyone has ever come across this issue before? I loaded up Chrome today and for some reason the entire left hand side of the elements section is broken.

I can navigate down using the keyboard arrows and see the breadcrumb selectors change (as shown in the picture) and for some reason the top of the document seems to display (but looks very odd indeed), but anything below the 'if greater than IE8' doesn't show whatsoever.

Has anyone ever experienced this before? Am i better reinstalling or launching a support ticket?

[image]

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, but I have no conditional comments for IE in my code. All I see is `<!DOCTYPE html>`. If you create a support ticket, I will follow up on it and post my info as well.

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=397046